# Unity script: scene to 3D led cube

Tags: matrix, unity-game-engine, 3d

I am a total beginner to Unity, but I'm getting familiar with the interface and the way scripts work with Game Objects. Some days ago, I came across with an article regarding a 3D LED Matrix controlled by Unity and since then I've been trying to make it work with my project.

**Original article**: http://philippseifried.com/blog/2014/10/29/3d-led-matrix-with-unity/

Basically, once the script is attached to an Orthographic camera (or at least that's what I understood from the article), the camera layers and "slices" the scene, transforms it into a pixel matrix and paints the result into some preview layers dynamically generated.

I have accomplished to attach the camera and get the preview layers to show up. However, I'm unable to get the final result the article shows, as preview layers show absolutely nothing. I think it has to do with the fact that the author is using some kind of transparent planes I have been unable to replicate.

[image]

It would be great if someone could guide me a bit to get the exact same result of the article by reading it and watching the last Vine, as it shows his Unity screen with the transparent layers working up and running.

Answer (score 0):

The script was looking at the background color to decided wether a pixel had to be painted or not. 
Changing the camera background to transparent (RGBA) was enough to see the final result.